# Как правильно написать?

Tags: морфология

"Подготовка I и II главы/глав диссертации" - как правильно написать?

Comment: Глав — [ЗДЕСЬ][1].


  [1]: http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%B8+%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%22&hl=ru&tbo=p&tbm=bks&num=100&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=365095l383842l0l387207l5l5l0l0l0l0l390l1631l2-2.3l5l0&oq=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%B8+%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=

Comment: Не просто Google, а Гугл-книгах — http://books.google.com 

В обычном Гугле полно чуши.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку слово "глава" относится к обеим, то будет "I и II глав".